# HTML and CSS alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the h1 tag days text 'Today, Tues, Weds, Thur' to align directly underneath and in the centre of the cloud images above it [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nC8Q.jpg). I've feel like I've tried everything but cant quite get it to position properly. The code is below. I've tried having them within the same div but to no avail.

```css
.bottom h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.bottom .weather img {
  display: inline-block;
}

.bottom .weatherdays h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-left: 18px;
}

.bottom .weatherdays .today {
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.bottom .weatherdays .tue {
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.bottom .weatherdays .wed {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.bottom .weatherdays .thur {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 531px) {
  .bottom .weather img {
    max-width: 30px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  .bottom .weatherdays h1 {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Weather</h1>
<div class="weather">
  <img src="images/bigcloud.png" alt="Big Cloud" />
  <img src="images/smallcloud.png" alt="Small Cloud" />
  <img src="images/smallcloud.png" alt="Small Cloud" />
  <img src="images/smallcloud.png" alt="Small Cloud" />
</div>
<div class="weatherdays">
  <h1 class="today">TODAY</h1>
  <h1 class="tue">TUE</h1>
  <h1 class="wed">WED</h1>
  <h1 class="thur">THUR</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example seems to be missing an element with the class bottom

Comment: Hi, the 'bottom' class is the Section of which all the above html is wrapped within.

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox should provide a simple solution...

```css
.bottom h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.bottom .weather img {
  display: inline-block;
}

.bottom .weatherdays h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-left: 18px;
}

.bottom .weatherdays .today {
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.bottom .weatherdays .tue {
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.bottom .weatherdays .wed {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.bottom .weatherdays .thur {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 531px) {
  .bottom .weather img {
    max-width: 30px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  .bottom .weatherdays h1 {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}

div.weather,
div.weatherdays {
  display: flex;
}

div.weather > *,
div.weatherdays > * {
  flex: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<h1>Weather</h1>
<div class="weather">
  <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x120" alt="Big Cloud" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x100" alt="Small Cloud" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x100" alt="Small Cloud" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x100" alt="Small Cloud" /></div>
</div>
<div class="weatherdays">
  <h1 class="today">TODAY</h1>
  <h1 class="tue">TUE</h1>
  <h1 class="wed">WED</h1>
  <h1 class="thur">THUR</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this has aligned the text properly but has now enlarged my images to fit to each of the h1 weather day tags

Comment: Put your images inside of `div`s. Using `display: flex` like this, the elements are each stretched 25% of the container's width. It's not noticeable with the `h1` because the text is contained within the element. The text stays the same and the whitespace around the text is stretched. With the images, the image is the whole element, so the whole image is stretched.

Comment: Thank you again for your quick reply. Are you suggesting I put the images in separate divs?

Comment: Yep. Put the `img` tags each into their own `div` and the image itself won't stretch. I updated my answer to this, too. I think that better suits what you wanted to happen. Note that the paths for the images from your code are relative, so I can't actually see them here.

Comment: I made another update. I used placeholder images because I don't have your cloud images. Instead of using `text-align: center` to center the text, I made the divs containing the images and the h1s also flex items. This allows me both to center the text and the images appropriately and align the cloud images properly (I noticed the "today" image is a little bigger).

Comment: Brilliant, really appreciate that! Thank you